# Handler, CountDownTimer and Timer is not working when phone goes in sleep

Tags: android, timer, handler, countdowntimer

I want to implement count timer functionality in my application. First I used Handler class for it using postDelay method it is working fine when phone is not goes in sleep. this same thing also happened with CountDownTimer and Timer class. When phone goes in sleep mode timer speed is decrease. This is happen randomly.

Comment: why would you want to "count" anything if you go to sleep? just go to bed, sleep well, and when you wake up check the current time and count anything you want but only when you are "alive"

Comment: I want to perform some task when count value become 5 and 0. So count should be continue in background

Comment: so use `AlarmManager` to wake up

Comment: Try to solve your problem using Service instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems

First of all some of devices like Xiaomi, Meizu, etc have Security app which can block work of background services.

[After android 7.0 there are features to block background too.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html?hl=ru) So you cannot just use simple `Service`.

Assuming that I guess best solution will be using [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) with `Intent Service` which will run your `postDelay`, `CountDownTimer`and `Timer`.

Comment: And Timer, Handler and others will no longer slow down if you use Wake Lock?